# preg match or preg replace to format links in a paragraph

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Is there a way to use preg_match or preg_replace to scan a paragraph and replace each pattern by a link?

Example:

```
... [keyword][http://mysite.com/keyword/] ... [another-keyword][http://mysite.com/another-keyword] ...
```

Which will be as follows:

```
... &lt;a href="http://mysite.com/keyword/"&gt;keyword&lt;/a&gt; ... &lt;a href="http://mysite.com/another-keyword/"&gt;another-keyword&lt;/a&gt; ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it would be best if you have a way to identify how they should be translated in some way like *bbcode* `[url=http://site.com]keyword[/url]`, but you don't need to do it that way if the pattern is easily picked out and not used or confused for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]\[(https?:[^\]"]+)\]/i','<a href="$2">$1</a>',$string);
```

Which assumes that all links start with http: or https: and that they don't contain any double-quotes. http://regexpal.com/ is a nice tool when trying to come up with these patterns.

However, if you have any control over these tags, I would really suggest you use an existing tagging scheme like bbcode rather than inventing your own. There's lots of existing code for parsing bbcode and it's going to be a lot more robust and well-tested than anything you can come up with. Can you trust the source of the string you're trying to parse? It's real easy to screw this up and create nasty security problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback('!\[([^\[\]]+)\]\[([^\[\]]+)\]!', 'callback', $in);

function callback($m){
    return "<a href=\"$m[2]\">$m[1]</a>";
}
```